# Batch Selected to active Baking

Tags: scripting, workflow, texture-baking

I have to bake several objects, in *combined* type. Each (lowpoly) object take baking information from a selection of another (highpoly) object(s). Here is my bake panel config:

[image: combined selected to active]

My problem is that i can only bake one object, wait for the texture to be baked, save it, then redo the task for the next object (with a new selection). So i can't set a list of render task to calculate by night 'cause it's not automate.

So :

- is there a plugin (free or not) which can do that ? (I buyed the baketool plugin which is very great, but don't support *selected to active* option *[edit] finally, it can, see answer below [/edit]*)
- can this task be send to network render ? (network renderer addon, render.st, etc)
- i don't know python at all but i have already write little script in another programming language : do you think it will be a pain to script a task like this ?

Comment: FYI, i've just seen that renderstreet don't support _selected to active_ option https://render.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/660826-texture-baking-in-blender

Comment: I am coming here from your comment in my previous question. Even I had to bake multiple objects one after the other in my project. All I had to do was select all the objects to be baked and hit the bake button. I could do this in GUI and through script. I was using cycles engine and I set up all the nodes, UV maps, and images before hand in the node editor for each object. So, can you try that and check once.

Comment: Thanks for come here. In the next days i'll try to learn basic python for blender, it can be very usefull in any case, i'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 1):

BakeTool addon can handle it !

There is a mode that i haven't try yet, which is the Atlas mode (default is individual).
The support of baketool answer me :

> There’s a “Target” option in the Atlas Mode. It works as the “Selected
>   to active”. On this mode all the objects in the Object List are used
>   as sources and the target is the “actived” one to be baked. See that
>   in this case the target need a valid non overlapped UV.

I definitively love this addon, anyone who use blender and make realtime 3d should have it :)

Answer (score -1):

**Bake Wrangler** can do batch baking.  It is **free**.

It is a 2019 add-on, so not many people discovered it yet.
I tested it and it can also bake from objects to another object.

The batch bake is in :-

- Editor type = Bake Node Editor (must download & enable this add-on first)
- Top bar > Add > Bake Wrangler > Batch Bake

Download at : https://blenderartists.org/t/bake-wrangler-node-based-baking-tool-set/1187732

For batching tutorial, you can see https://youtu.be/1QpybXsNcsw?t=965