# Launch the full Dialouge of another script from within my own script (Export Add_On)

Tags: python, scripting, export

I have written a small add on that allows a user to create a mesh in a particular way. Once the mesh has been created I would like the user to be able to export the mesh to a dxf file for various reasons.

I have been able to figure out how to enable the 'io_export_dxf' add_on from within my own script while checking to see if it is already activate or not.

The issue is when I actually run the dxf export operator from the console or the script it does not launch the full built in dialogue box for file export that the add_on has built in to itself. From reading multiple post I can see that this is the intended function.  However, I would like the end user to have the full functionality of the dxf export add_on without having to go to the File Menu - Export Menu - Autocad DXF selection.  I tried other built-in export and import operators to make sure that it was not only this one particular add_on and I get the same results.

In short...I would like to run any built-in import or export operator from within my script and have it use the existing add_ons pre-built dialogue.

Any help  you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193237/is-it-possible-to-write-a-script-which-opens-blenders-existing-fbx-exporter-win

Comment: That was it!! I was obviously using the wrong search term. Thank you very much.  Sorry I am a newbie so I am not sure how I can make a comment an Answer.